# How to draw Images canvas at faster rate from websocket onmessageevent

Tags: html5-canvas, png, webgl

I have written a websocket implementation for image transfer from server to javascript client.

In the client side on the event `this.webSocket.onmessage` we are receiving a png image as base64 and we write as below to display.

```
if (bIsPngFormat) { 
  // Draw the image onto canvas using image.onload event
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.onload = () => {
    this.ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
  }
  myImage.src = "data:image/png;base64," + renderableImage
}
```

But the display is not refreshing even through the event is fired at the rate of 90 frames/sec

Just want to know why canvas is not getting refreshed with new incoming image when it comes very fast.

Will it work better when used canvas with openGL context or directly send the RGBA buffer (instead of base64 png) and rendered using below code

Code:

```
// Apply the uint8array buffer received from websocket onmessage
var iData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(renderableImage), width, height);
this.ctx.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you send smaller images? Are the images changing alot?

Comment: You will most likely be limited to 60 FPS either way. Sending data directly (gzip compressed, which is almost equivalent to png) is worth a try, since it avoids another async call which could mess up the order.